# " This document has no pages " error in PDFTRON

Tags: pdftron

I want to convert DWG format to PDF format in angular 4 / nodeJS and trying to implement it using PDFTRON CAD Modules but every time i'm getting error like `InvalidPDF : This document has no pages.` even if DWG have multiple pages. 
I have tried following code :-

```
        await PDFNet.initialize();
        const pdfDoc = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.create();
        PDFNet.addResourceSearchPath('src/client/lib/lib/Lib/');

        PDFNet.Convert.fromCAD(pdfDoc, 'src/files/example.dwg', new PDFNet.Obj);
        pdfDoc.saveMemoryBuffer(PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_remove_unused).then(value => {
          // const arr = new Uint8Array(value);
          const blob = new Blob([value], {type: 'application/pdf'});
          instance.docViewer.getDocument().mergeDocument(blob, instance.docViewer.getPageCount() + 1);


          // const doc = instance.CoreControls.createDocument(blob, {filename: 'src/client/files/demo.pdf'});

          // instance.loadDocument(blob, { filename: 'src/client/files/newPDF.pdf'});
        });
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in my code. Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Does this issue happen with any DWG file? What happens when you run the CAD2PDFTest sample project that comes with SDK download?

Comment: Will let you know once CAD2PDFTest sample project run !!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ryan .The issue was, CAD module file's are not properly extracted into my current SDK. So i extracted CAD Modules again into another new folder and pasted all folder's content into the SDK folder. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. For anyone else reading this, the easiest thing to do is to unzip the CADModule.zip file from inside the PDFNet SDK folder, so all the Lib and Sample files are extracted into the correct folders for you. Otherwise, you can manually copy over the files in the Lib and Samples folders.